# XORing two pointer in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, xor, xor-linkedlist

I want to implement an XOR linked list in **c++**.

I wrote a function that give me the XOR of two pointer.
Here it is.

```
XORLinkedList::Node *XORLinkedList::getXOR(XORLinkedList::Node *a, XORLinkedList::Node *b) {

    size_t A = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(a);
    size_t B = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(b);

    return (XORLinkedList::Node *) (A ^ B);
}
```

I searched and tried to write this and this was what came to my mind.

I don't know if it works or not or it is even right.

if you know how to do it please tell me

Comment: Two quick immediate problems about your function when seen in isolation: 1) `size_t` is not the same thing as `std::intptr_t`, which is what you should be using here. 2) Your hybrid representation of two XORed pointers is not usable as a pointer, so it should not be stored as one, so your function should also return a `std::intptr_t`